# What are the possible reasons for rendering error in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, rendering

I am using android studio 5.0. When I open an Activity Layout to preview, Layout doesn't appear and give an error "Render problem". Does anyone knows how it can be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your android version on your designer preview , which is render your xml.[image]

Answer (score 0):

**From [Android Tools](http://tools.android.com/knownissues)**,

Layout rendering problems in Android Studio can be fixed by,

> **Workaround 1**: First manually build the project, then manually sync the
> project (using the Sync with Gradle files in the toolbar, or from the
> Tools > Android menu), then finally press Refresh in the toolbar above
> the layout editor.
>
> **Workaround 2:** Switch the Android Gradle plugin from
> 1.2.x to 1.1.3 for now. When 1.2.3 is released you can switch back to the 1.2.x versions.
>
> **Workaround 3:** If the above workarounds don't work
> for you, and you are on windows, please try downloading a build from
> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6b7eYGgoFdCTWFyYWlySExjUlE/view
> which probably solves the issue.